# Does Fréchet derivative needs continuity?

Tags: functional-analysis, optimal-control, frechet-derivative

I want to ask a question that I feel everyone acts as if it is a common knowledge. I am really new to functional analysis. How does Fréchet differentiability imply continuity? In the definition I have only continuity of the derivative itself,A, is mentioned:

A mapping F : U ⊂ U → V is said to be Fréchet differentiable
at u ∈ U if there exist an operator A ∈ L(U,V ) and a mapping r(u,·) : U →
V with the following properties: for all h ∈ U such that u + h ∈ U, we have
F(u + h) = F(u) + Ah + r(u,h)
where the so-called remainder r satisfies the condition
$\frac{||r(u,h)||_V}{||h||_U} $
→ $0$ as $|h||_U$ → 0.
The operator A is then called the Fréchet derivative of F at u, and we write
A = F ? (u). If A is Fréchet differentiable at every point u ∈ U, then A is said
to be Fréchet differentiable in U.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$F(u+h)-F(u) \to 0$ as $h \to 0$ because $Ah \to 0$ as $h \to 0 $  and $r(u,h) =\|h\|_U \frac {r(u,h)} {\|h\|_U} \to 0$ too. [$\|Ah\| \leq \|A\| \|h\|_U \to 0$].

Comment: @stkcn tr I will be glad to provide more details if necessary.